# Laravel 6 PayPal GateWay subTotal,shipping ,tax not working properly

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, laravel-6.2

Am using Laravel 6. And am trying to integrate PayPal Payment Gateway in my project.
Am following PayPal PHP Sdk's example source code.

I have sandbox personal & buyer account. 

Payment and transaction working when am copying code from PayPal PHP Payment Example.
But whenever am trying to add Multiple items and subTotal then its generate error.

Code Below : 
Static data from PayPal Sdk's Example.

```
$item1 = new Item();
    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setSku("22222") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice(7.5);
    $item2 = new Item();
    $item2->setName('Granola bars')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(5)
        ->setSku("852520") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice(2);
    $iteamArr = [$item1,$item2];

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems($iteamArr);
```

Default example Payment Details Below :

and What am trying to make dynamic .

Code Below :

```
    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping(7.5)
        ->setTax(5.0)
        ->setSubtotal(17.50);


    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
        ->setTotal(30)
        ->setDetails($details);
```

My Dynamic Process is :

```
    for($loop=1;$loop<3;$loop++){

        $item = new Item();
        $itemInfo[]=$item->setName('Dynamic Name '.$loop)
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setSku(rand(1111,9999).$loop) // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
            ->setPrice(2);

    }
```

According to My Dynamic Code , Payment Detail's below :

```
$details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping(7.5)
        ->setTax(5.0)
        ->setSubtotal(4);


    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
        ->setTotal(16.5)
        ->setDetails($details);
```

After this am getting reply from PayPal return

```
Got Http response code 400 when accessing 
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.
```

Note : When am cloning PayPal item information from there documentation its successfully working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem probably should be     `->setTotal(16.5)`

This line should be dynamic too, since the total price is dynamic in base of checkout cart

I'm going to give you as example a part of code from my paypal PaymentController:

```
$totalPayment = ($request->get('actual_participants') * $trip->price);        

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item = new Item();

        $item->setName($trip->title) /** item name **/
            ->setCurrency($trip->currency->currency_type)
            ->setQuantity('1')
            ->setPrice($totalPayment); /** unit price **/

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems(array($item));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency($trip->currency->currency_type)
            ->setTotal($totalPayment);
```

11 months later I think that you already solved the problem but I wish good luck to other devs because I understand the struggle of paypal integration :)

Comment: yes . Its solved. Btw thank you so much for your contribution.